# Capsule Networks - Facial Expression Recognition

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I want to experiment Capsule Networks on FER. For now I am using fer2013 Kaggle dataset.

One thing that I didn't understand in Capsule Net was in the first conv layer, size was reduced to 20x20 - having input image as 28x28 and filters as 9x9 with 1 stride. But in the capsules, the size reduces to 6x6. How did this happen? Because with input size as 20x20 and filters as 9x9 and 2 strides, I couldn't get 6x6. Maybe I missed something.

For my experiment, input size image is 48x48. Should I use the same hyperparams for the start or is there any suggested hyperparams that I can use?

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning, the picture is 28*28 and you apply a kernel of size 9, so you lose (9-1) pixels. (4 for each side). So at the end of the first convolutional layer, you have (28-8)*(28-8)=20*20 pixels, and you apply the same kernel, so again, (20-8)*(20-8)=12*12. But for the second layer the stride is 2, so there is only 12/2=6 pixels left.

With 48*48 pixel, if you apply the same convolutional layer, you will have at the end 16*16 picture. ((48-8-8)/2)

Answer (score 1):

Standard Capsnet has two convolution layers. the first one has stride of 1 and the second one has 2.

if you want to have 6*6 capsule numbers, your filter size should be 19*19.

because:

```
48 - (19-1) = 30

30 - (19-1) = 12

12 / 2 = 6  (because stride is 2)
```